# HTML is corrupted when calling Html.RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following partial view, which is just a test bit of HTML, nothing final

```
@model int
<div id="media-wrapper">
    <span id="foo">For more details, click here:</span>
    <iframe width="260" height="215"></iframe>
</div>
```

To use this view I call:

`@{ Html.RenderPartial("_MediaLink", Model.PartnerId); }`

In Chrome's dev tools, the `<iframe>` is rendered like so:

`<iframe width="260" height="215">
</iframe width="260" height="215">`

For some reason, it's attributes are duplicated. Looking at the `<iframe>` in Chrome dev tools, it is not coloured the same as other elements on the page. e.g. a `<div class='test'>` will have the div coloured red and class coloured orangy-brown. The iframe is entirely red.

Also the `<iframe>` is not in the DOM of the page. If you use, say, jQuery to find it, then I always see `undefined` in any queries.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: An `<iframe>` cannot be self-closed. You must use `<iframe></iframe>`.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally removed the closing tag. I replaced it just now, but the original problem still persists.

Comment: FWIW I'm not able to reproduce this under MVC 4.

Comment: I tried a fresh, new, MVC 4 app. Created a new partial view, with the same `<iframe>` stuff as you see above. Got the same problem. Weird.

Comment: Even putting the `<iframe>` directly into the Home Index view file results in the same problem. Huh, what the hell am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? Perhaps something in your Chrome is messing with the HTML.

Comment: Tried IE11, same issue.

Comment: I asked a colleague to do the same, using MVC 5. In both IE and Chrome the `<iframe>` appeared correctly.

Comment: Then a couple of things I can think of: anti-virus software or firewall modifying the HTML because the software thinks it's potentially harmful.

Comment: Yeah I think it's a software issue. Rather than adding more comments, I'll go away and have a look further into this from the external software level, not the MVC level. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Try and take a look with Fiddler or Wireshark to see incoming network traffic. Good luck!

Comment: I created a `.html` file, with the `<iframe>` in it, and that renders fine. So it's the Razor view engine that's at fault here. Will look into this further.

Comment: Corrupted .NET installation then?